# An abstract class with more implementation or a non-abstract class?

Tags: java

I am working on a game which has a class called Tank.
Every tank has an object of class called `TankParameters`. `TankParameter` consists of tank's velocity, rotation velocity and health.

At the moment my plan is to make `TankParameters` class abstract and pass in different implementation of `TankParameters` class to `Tank` class. So let's say I will have an implementation called `LightTankParameters` which will set attributes accordingly. Or I may have a `HeavyTankParameters` which will set attributes accordingly.

Now my question is rather than let's say creating so many classes extending `TankParameters` will it be more efficient to make `TankParameters` as a non-abstract class and have a constructor setting up the variables with the values provided or it will better to keep creating classes for different `TankParameters` types.

I am asking this question as I may add features in game with which people can modify their tanks and hence the tank parameters.

Also if having more implementations are better then what is a better way of setting variables

Is it

```
public class LightTankParameters extends TankParameters{

    private static final int MAX_HEALTH = 100;

    public LightTankParameters() {
        super(MAX_HEALTH);
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class LightTankParameters extends TankParameters{

    public LightTankParameters() {
        super(100);
    }
}
```

And here is my TankParameters class

```
public abstract class TankParameters {
    /**
     * Max health of the tank
     */
    protected int maxHealth;
......
}
```

Comment: The question is not about efficiency rather design. It would be better to keep an abstract Tankparameter and have different implementation. Because of different implementations, if you add something to light parameter you dont have to unnecessarily use it in Heavy parm

Comment: The best way of setting up properties is from an outside source (e.g. a properties file), that makes it a lot easier to change them for testing or even in production. Also if you've got a class that is difficult to construct because the constructor would have many parameters, some of them optional, you may want to take a look at the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: I think it would be better to do away with `TankParameter` and just have different types of `Tank`.

Comment: if you want to allow flexible customization baking in an inheritance hierarchy is probably not a good start. maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5914473/217324 for something similar.

Comment: I agree with@ markspace. Seems like all of the variables in TankParameters should just be instance variables of tank.

Comment: And another thing: don't be afraid to prototype all the ideas you have and see what leads to simpler, easily modifiable and testable code. Then throw the other one away. I find that often that's the best way of learning how to make tricky design decisions.

Comment: Do you really need different classes here, or could you just have `TankParameters LIGHT = new TankParameters(100)` (having declared the class non-abstract, obvs) (or an enum)?

Comment: @AndyTurner yes that is something I was thinking about. There are many ways this can be done and I am really thinking what is the best way to do it.

Comment: @biziclop yes one of the main reason for constructing tank parameters was to get rid of huge constructors.

Comment: In that case Builders can really help you.

Comment: Here is the reason I was going with tank parameters. I posted a question few days ago. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/299552/should-i-use-strategy-design-pattern-or-something-else?noredirect=1#comment623741_299552

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a job for Creational design patterns [Creational design patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/creational_patterns). Sounds like you need multiple implementations of an single interface. Based on what you have Explained this sounds like one of the `Factory Patterns` would work for you (this should be vetted another creational pattern may work better for you like Builder patter). Its difficult to Specify the exact creational pattern to use without having a holistic view of your entire setup. I would suggest looking at the different creational design patterns and see which works best for your setup.

Comment: That's the strategy I would follow. There's no need to make your code more complex adding this extra layer of inheritance just to say you are creating a tank with different parameters.

Use a factory and let its method names be explicitly enough about the different sorts of tanks you're producing.